# How to go about refactoring/rebuilding a WPF application developed in WinForms style

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms, performance, refactoring

I am working on a Wpfapplication developed in a WinForms style; I am saying this because application consists -

- UserControls having more then 2000 lines of code (without any regions, members scattered all over the class). No separation of concerns whatsoever.
- UserControls having ~1000 lines of code and corresponding ViewModel having another 1000 lines of code.
- UserControls having a lot of event handlers (some having > 25).
- UserControls having nested classes.
- UserControls implementing INotifyPropertyChanged and having DP's.
- Lot of unused classes/code (although referenced/used in code but not doing anything);
- More then 30 MultiValue converters and 40 value converters.
- Converter instances are used frequently in code behind/VM.
- Few MultiValue converters

  - having hundreds of lines of code (few having upto 400 lines of code).
  - having business logic inside them.
  - creating the ViewModel instances.
  - having Nested classes.
  - exposing methods used by user controls in code behind.
  - exposing properties used by user controls in code behind and view models.
  - having static methods returning observable collections/Lists, used by other converters & View Models.
  - exposing events, subscribed by UserControl's and view model's.
  - Implementing IDisposable.
- Converters are used extensively to create/set the DataContext and ItemSources of controls/ListViews/DataGrids:

like this -

```
<Editor:EditorControl.DataContext>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource EditorControlModelConverter}">
        <Binding
            ElementName="UserControl"
            Path="RefId" />
        <Binding
            ElementName="UserControl"
            Path="CollectionView.SelectedScenario" />
        <Binding
            ElementName="UserControl"
            Path="ParentComponentName" />
    </MultiBinding>
</Editor:EditorControl.DataContext>
```

and this -

```
<ListView.ItemsSource>
<MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ItemsSourceInsertConverter}">
    <Binding
        ElementName="EditorControl"
        Path="EditorControl.ContextListEnabled" />
    <Binding
        ElementName="EditorControl"
        Path="EditorContainer.ParentComponent.Model.ModelList" />
    <Binding
        ElementName="EditorControl"
        Path="EditorContainer.ParentComponent.Model.CategoryModelList" />
    <Binding
        ElementName="EditorControl"
        Path="EditorContainer.ParentComponent.Model.ItemSortOrder" />
    <Binding
        ElementName="EditorControl"
        Path="IsItemSourceMatrixInsertConverterSuspended" />
    <Binding
        ElementName="EditorControl"
        Path="EditorControlModel.IsUpdating" />
    <Binding
        ElementName="EditorControl"
        Path="EditorControlModel.ContextListEnabledInitialized" />
    <Binding
        BindsDirectlyToSource="true"
        ElementName="listView" />
    <Binding
        ElementName="EditorControl"
        Path="EditorControlModel" />
    <Binding
        ElementName="EditorControl"
        Path="EditorContainer.Plugin.FeatureManager.EditorCategoryFeatureEnabled" />
    <Binding
        ElementName="EditorControl"
        Path="EditorContainer.Plugin.FeatureManager.EditorMatrixFeaturesEnabled" />
</MultiBinding>
```

List goes on...Has any one of you faced similar situation and how you dealt with it? what approach should be taken to refactor this kind of application for better performance and maintainability?

---

**Update:**

Answer of Andrew's Q - "Why we need to refactor this":

1. Performance - we are not happy with the performance of our application and feel it should be better(considering the functionality and usability).
2. Better Extensibility : we are still in early stages of our product and know that a lot of new features needs to be added in future; but looking at the current code base it looks tough and may break old functionality.
3. Better Maintainability : It will be tough to maintain a non standards-compliant/ tricky/hacky code in future(it's very imp. as we see this product running for years to come).

Comment: Yes, the first thing I'd do is post a question on Stack Overflow with an intentionally inflammatory title, like "Refactoring a WPF application built by an [incompetent] WinForms developer". *Oh wait...*

Comment: To be honest, I don't see much here that could be tagged as "Winforms" development.  If they're using view models, converters, and binding, they are clearly attempting to use MVVM, they just made a mess of it.  I would start by asking "Do I have to?"  If the answer is yes, buy Resharper.  That will show you everything that's not referenced anywhere.  Remove all that, then just start refactoring and cleaning up where it makes sense.  Resharper can do a lot for you without much effort from you.  Even with that though, it still looks like you have a lot of work ahead of you.

Comment: I did not even know you could expose an event in a converter.

Comment: @CodyGray: I agree that it can be considered as inflammatory but thats not my intention and reading 'incompetent' between the lines is your personal view; I never said the person developed is incompetent (and don't agree with that); this is the way I have seen a lot of (good) WinFomrs devs work in WPF without knowing that Winform way of coding can be/is wrong in WPF.

Comment: @Josh : Thanks for your comment and I agree with you; why I used WinForms style is based on my exp. working with WinForms developers working in WPF; these are some of the things which they do wrongly in WPF without knowing it; I am already using Resharper and trying to use it to refactor the code but as you said it's still a lot of work ahead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd ask the question *why* do you need to refactor this? if the answer is "So its standards compliant", "It looks better" or "So our development team is happy" then I'd seriously reconsider doing it.

If the answer is "Because we are unable to meet business needs due to difficulty of changing/updating our application" then you have a valid business reason.

I've worked on many projects where my first instinct was to scrap and rewrite it. Many of those I did actually scrap and rewrite, only to find out half way through that the original developers, while they didn't do it the way I would (or even had poor coding standards) had fixed a lot of issues I'd never considered!

Similarly I've worked on one or two where a rewrite or deep refactor had a strong business reason and the outcome was a success. Nevertheless its always painful to make these changes.

So. In conclusion, if I had to do this due to a strong business need, I would probably start by creating a test script (manual testing) or better yet, automated tests (UI or UNit Tests, doesnt matter) which coarsely test the functionality of your application.

Then I would take Views in turn and creating ViewModels for them, moving functionality out to ViewModels. For instance, moving the dependency properties & INotifyPropertyChanged to a VM.

I would then look at Dependency Injection e.g. StructureMap to wire up dependencies required into those viewmodels or some other method to keep coupling low.

These techniques and others are outlined in the book, [Brownfield Application Development in .NET](http://www.manning.com/baley/).

Finally I would look back in glory at my pretty code which does half the features that the old application did. Joke! Ok this last part was facecious, I do think there are many reasons why this is a very good thing (refactoring), however I have learned from bitter experience to not take these decisions lightly.

Best regards!

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I really appreciate your positive response; this is the kind of response I was looking for.

Comment: Answer to Why we need to do this: 
1. Performance - we are not happy with the performance of our application and feel it should be better(considering the functionality and usability). 
2. Better Extensibility : we are still in early stages of our product and know that a lot of new features needs to be added in future; but looking at the current code base it looks tough and may break old functionality.
3. Better Maintainability : It will be tough to maintain a non standards-compliant/ tricky/hacky code in future(and we see this product running for years to come).

Comment: Thanks akjoshi, appreciate the additional info. Regarding performance, what exactly is the bottleneck? Be descriptive. Extensibility/maintainability - agree with you but do you have any actual case study where you are struggling to maintain? If your project is early you can consider a blanket re-write but take great care, often its the case that when you rewrite code you end up with half the features and half the old problems you used to have anyway!

Comment: We are not happy with performnace and bottleneck is that with this kind of code its not possible to find the real bottleneck! and doesn't look like we will be able to solve that problem even if we somehow find it. 
Case study: Not really, as most of the feature set is complete(as of now) and even fixing small bugs gets tricky/hacky because of the code base.
Rewriting is not an option currently because of the reasons you mentiond earlier(feature set and issues already taken care) and lack of domain(product) expertise.

Comment: @akjoshi have you used a third party profiler on your application, such as JetBrains dotTrace (recommended) or Ants profiler? These will help you pinpoint exactly where a performance bottleneck is. It's often in the most surprising (and unexpected) places! Regarding refactor/rewrite, I'm not trying to discourage you, just warn of the caveats. If anything I'd favour refactoring over rewrite (unless its a small app, then bin it and start again) as that will help you keep your feature set while improving code quality. Take a look at Brownfield Application Development in .NET book I mentioned.

Comment: @akjoshi ok, if your app is in early dev (its a prototype then) it makes it more important to address these issues as you said in your edited Q. First up I'd start by creating viewmodels for each usercontrol and having a repeated pattern to instantiate view/vm, set datacontext on view (ie: wire up). From there you can start to move functionality piece by piece to viewmodel. Before doing so you need coarse manual tests/automated UI tests/unit tests to prove you didnt break it. Do it a bit at a time and retest regularly. You can rewrite whole apps in place and its quite fun thing to do!

Comment: I have used ANTS profiler and some other profilers a lot in my past; from that exp. I feel it is not worth doing that at this point, considering the Spaghetti code we currently have. Moreover, we are not even using the power of WPF.

Comment: @akjoshi I am always surprised when people quote the "power of WPF". Did you know its far slower than windows forms for real-time rendering despite using the GPU? For styling, transparency and effects I have no doubt its faster. Just writing high performance apps in WPF is actually very hard to achieve. Run jetbrains profiler on it (better than ANTS which ironically is VERY slow!). You might be surprised what it turns up ...

Answer (score 2):

I would start out by commenting out the unused code.  Next, start rewriting the windows one by one.

Other than that, work in a branch and check in often so you can revert to known good points.

There's no free lunch - just get to work and stop complaining on SO about it!

Comment: Thanks RQDQ; I agree there are no free lunches available but there is no harm in taking advice from others and that's what my intention was and to let others know what all can go wrong & how badly. I apologise if that wasted your/others time.